# How to draw route from A to B through multiple points on GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Imagine I want to go from A to B through 3 waypoints. I have this code, which forms the Google Maps direction URL:

```
fun getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(): String {
    val origin = "origin=" + currentLocation.latitude + "," + currentLocation.longitude;
    val waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|" + loc1.latitude + "," + loc1.longitude + "|" + loc2.latitude + "," + loc2.longitude + "|" + loc3.latitude + "," + loc3.longitude
    val destination = "destination=" + loc4.latitude + "," + loc4.longitude
    val sensor = "sensor=false"
    val key = "key="+API_KEY;
    val params = "$origin&$waypoints&$destination&$sensor&$key"
    val output = "json"

    val url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + params
    System.out.println("map url: "+url)
    return url
}
```

Opening the URL on browser gave this:

> {    "routes" : [],    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" }

But if I only use 1 waypoint (instead of 3 like shown above), the direction will be displayed in 1 big JSON correctly, like this:

> {    "geocoded_waypoints" : [
> {
> "geocoder_status" : "OK",
> "place_id" : "ChIJH87yjIXxaS4R5_ww8ZCufeo",
> "types" : [ "clothing_store", "establishment", "point_of_interest", "store" ]
> },
> {
> "geocoder_status" : "OK",
> "place_id" : "ChIJ1wVXzIDxaS4RkyUYgf3ZV0c",
> "types" : [ "street_address" ]
> },
> {
> "geocoder_status" : "OK",
> "place_id" : "ChIJrfOSGBXxaS4Ro595K_5ClCg",
> "types" : [ "establishment", "hospital", "point_of_interest" ]
> }    ],    "routes" : [
> {
> "bounds" : {
> "northeast" : {
> "lat" : -6.2399232,
> "lng" : 106.8161445
> },
> "southwest" : {
> "lat" : -6.2684858,
> "lng" : 106.7929824
> }
> },
> "copyrights" : "Map data ©2019 Google",
> "legs" : [
> {
> "distance" : {
> "text" : "1.2 km",
> "value" : 1205
> },
> "duration" : {
> "text" : "4 mins",
> "value" : 254
> },
> "end_address" : "Jl. Kemang Raya No.54, RT.8/RW.2, Bangka, Kec. Mampang Prpt., Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus
> Ibukota Jakarta 12730, Indonesia",
> "end_location" : {
> "lat" : -6.263443499999999,
> "lng" : 106.8160131....

So does it mean I can only use 1 waypoint?

Comment: Probably there is no way from origin to destination via waypoints set. Can you share  full URL from line `System.out.println("map url: "+url);` (without KEY of course)?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Please check this 2 URLs: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-6.2684059,106.8103103&waypoints=optimize:true|-6.263459,106.815903|-6.240607,106.792831|-6.263459,106.815903&destination=-6.240607,106.792831&sensor=false&key=..... and
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-6.2684059,106.8103103&waypoints=optimize:true%7C-6.263459,106.815903%7C-6.240607,106.792831%7C-6.240607,106.792831&destination=-6.235759,6.823277&sensor=false&key=..... The first one works, the second doesn't. All the positions refer to valid locations in Jakarta.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way from origin to destination via waypoints set. The second URL:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-6.2684059,106.8103103&waypoints=optimize:true%7C-6.263459,106.815903%7C-6.240607,106.792831%7C-6.240607,106.792831&destination=-6.235759,6.823277&sensor=false&key=<YOUR_KEY>`

contains unreachable destination `destination=-6.235759,6.823277` in Atlantic Ocean. Probably destination should be `106.823277` instead of  `6.823277` : `destination=-6.235759,106.823277` if all the positions should refer to valid locations in Jakarta. So, double check code, that compose URL for Directions API request.